# Muting and Unmuting multiple audio media on one slide in Powerpoint using VBA

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I use PowerPoint 2016 on Windows 10. Slide A has a text box and a command button. When the command button is selected, a boolean `gbool` is set and  the presentation advances to Slide B.

```
ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.GotoSlide <slideB slideindex>
```

On Slide B, there are two audio media objects, AM1 and AM2. What I want to happen is if `gbool` is True then AM1 should play else AM2 should play. I have used the muted flag to attempt this:

```
Shape.MediaFormat.Muted = False
```

The problem I have is that, this sometimes works, other times both audio medias will play.
The code looks like this:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim osl As Slide, oSh As Shape, gbool As Boolean
    gbool = function()

    Set osl = ActivePresentation.Slides(<slideB slideindex>)
    Set oSh = osl.Shapes("AM1")
    oSh.MediaFormat.Muted = gbool
    Set oSh = osl.Shapes("AM2")
    oSh.MediaFormat.Muted = Not gbool

   ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.GotoSlide <slideB slideindex>
End Sub
```

Any ideas for the random behaviour and is there a better way to do this?

Comment: What is "gbool = Function()" supposed to do?
Also, it's a VERY good idea to add Option Explicit to the top of each module; that'll make sure you declare all variables.

Comment: Function returns a boolean.

Comment: Thanks, but that much is obvious. It returns true or false based on what, though?

Comment: Does it matter. It has no bearing on the problem. The problem is why the switching of muting the audio between to two audio only works sometimes, othertimes both audios can be heard.

Comment: Since the muted/unmuted state of the audio depends on the value of gbool, it'd make sense to step through the code while it's running to verify that the value is what you expect it to be.

Comment: Please think before making a comment. It doesn't matter what the value of gbool is, one audio should be muted and the other unmuted. As I mentioned above, 50% i=of the time, both audios are unmuted. I am wondering if my code only updates some cache, if there is a cache, and so the value of muted is not being picked up and used.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have an answer - at least this method works all the time. Instead of using the muted property of the MediaFormat object, I now use the PlayOnEntry property of the Play Settings object. So the change looks like this:

```
Set osl = ActivePresentation.Slides(<slideB slideindex>)
Set oSh = osl.Shapes("AM1")
oSh.AnimationSettings.PlaySettings.PlayOnEntry = gbool
Set oSh = osl.Shapes("AM2")
oSh.AnimationSettings.PlaySettings.PlayOnEntry = Not gbool
```

If there is a better way, I would appreciate to know it.